# TikZ-UML relations seem anchored in middle of class

Tags: latex, tikz

I'm trying to draw an inheritance tree with VHV relations with consistent leg lengths. I find that the lengths change according to the sizes of the contents of the class boxes.

Here's the (not so M)WE:

```
\documentclass[border={1cm 1cm 1cm 1cm}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.pathreplacing, 
fadings, shadings, shapes, arrows, positioning,patterns,automata}

\newcommand{\derivedown}[4]{
    \umlclass[below=1cm of #1.south, anchor=north]{#2}{#3}{#4}
    \umlinherit{#2}{#1}}
\newcommand{\derivedownt}[5]{
    \umlclass[below=1cm of #1.south, anchor=north, template=#3]{#2}{#4}{#5}
    \umlinherit{#2}{#1}}
\newcommand{\derivedownleft}[4]{
    \umlclass[below left=1cm and 0.5cm of #1.south, anchor=north east]{#2}{#3}{#4}
    \umlVHVinherit[arm2=-1.5cm]{#2}{#1}}
\newcommand{\siblingleft}[5]{
    \umlclass[left=1cm of #1.north west, anchor=north east]{#3}{#4}{#5}
    \umlVHVinherit[arm2=-1.5cm]{#3}{#2}}
\newcommand{\siblingright}[5]{
    \umlclass[right=1cm of #1.north east, anchor=north west]{#3}{#4}{#5}
    \umlVHVinherit[arm2=-1.5cm]{#3}{#2}}
\newcommand{\note}[2]{
    \umlnote[below left=0.5cm and 0.5cm of #1.north east, anchor=south west]{#1}{#2}
    }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \umlclass{RefCount}{int refs;}{AddRef();Release();}
    \note{RefCount}{deletes this on release to zero}
    \derivedown{RefCount}{Event}{int id, prio}{}
    \derivedown{Event}{EventAgent}{}{\umlvirt{deliver()=0;}\\ \umlvirt{getDeliveryTarget()=0;}}
    \derivedown{EventAgent}{SyncEventAgent}{id=kAgentEventId}{send(IEventDispatcher dis) \{ \\ \hskip1em AddRef(); \\ \hskip1em dis.isThreadCurrent() \\ \hskip2em ? deliver() \\ \hskip2em : dis.sendEventSync(this); \\ \hskip1em Release(); \} }
    \siblingleft{SyncEventAgent}{EventAgent}{SyncRetEventAgent}{}{}
    \siblingright{SyncEventAgent}{EventAgent}{AsyncEventAgent}{}{send/remove(IEventDispatcher dis) \{ \\ \hskip1em dis.send/remove(this); \}}
    \derivedownt{SyncRetEventAgent}{SyncRetEventAgentN}{T...}{}{}
    \derivedownt{SyncEventAgent}{SyncEventAgentN}{T...}{}{}
    \derivedownt{AsyncEventAgent}{AsyncEventAgentN}{T...}{}{}

    \umlclass[right=10cm of RefCount]{IEventDispatcher}{}{\umlvirt{send/remove events} \\ \umlvirt{add/remove listener for id} \\ \umlvirt{isThreadCurrent()}}
    \derivedown{IEventDispatcher}{EventDispatcher}{}{}
    \derivedownleft{EventDispatcher}{EventThread}{}{}
    \siblingright{EventThread}{EventDispatcher}{Selector}{}{}

    \umlclass[right=2cm of EventDispatcher]{EventListenerNode}{}{}
    \umluniaggreg[mult2=*]{EventDispatcher}{EventListenerNode}

    \umlclass[right=10cm of IEventDispatcher]{IEventListener}{}{\umlvirt{void receiveEvent(Event*)}}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

On the result you'll see a fork below EventAgent and another below EventDispatcher, but they have different leg lengths. If you take out all 3 of the [arm2=-1.5cm] options, you'll see that the three-way fork at the left becomes lopsided. The figure -1.5cm was strange to begin with, but that's what I needed to get it roughly correct.

I'd have thought that out of the box there'd be no reason for these leg lengths to depend on the size of the box. They should be measured from where they join the edge of the class box.

How do I fix this?

PS: By changing the first macro to:

```
\newcommand{\derivedown}[4]{
    \umlclass[below=1cm of #1.south, anchor=north]{#2}{#3}{#4}
    \umlinherit[name=under#1, anchor1=90, anchor2=90]{#2}{#1}
    \umlpoint{under#1-1}}
```

we see where the inheritance arrows are centered, and indeed they seem to stretch between the midpoints of the class boxes. I tried every combination of arm1/2 options, including none, to no avail.